Why is alertType null?
I'm trying to implement an alert system in Swift that can be extended for different alert types. I created a base alert class and a subclass for login-related alerts. However, when I try to display the alert, the app crashes due to a runtime error where alertManager.alertType is nil.
Here is my base class:
import SwiftUI

class BaseAlert: Equatable {
    static let error = BaseAlert()

    static func == (lhs: BaseAlert, rhs: BaseAlert) -> Bool {
        return lhs === rhs
    }
}

And its child class:
class LoginAlert: BaseAlert {
    static let unverified = LoginAlert()
    static let verification = LoginAlert()
}

Next, I created an alert manager class to manage alerts:
import SwiftUI

class AlertManager<T: BaseAlert>: ObservableObject {
    @Published var errorMessage: String = ""
    @Published var alertType: T?
    @Published var isAlerting: Bool = false

    func showError(_ error: Error) {
        errorMessage = error.localizedDescription

        alertType = BaseAlert.error as? T

        isAlerting = true
    }

    func show(_ alertType: T) {
        self.alertType = alertType

        isAlerting = true
    }
}

Finally, I use this in my SwiftUI view like so:
@StateObject private var alertManager = AlertManager<LoginAlert>()

For error case:
alertManager.showError(error)

For other case:
alertManager.show(.unverified)

Showing alert:
.alert(isPresented: $alertManager.isAlerting) {
    switch alertManager.alertType! {
        case .unverified:
            return Alert(
                title: Text("Action Message"),
                message: Text("Your account is unverified. Please check your email inbox to activate it."),
                dismissButton: .cancel(Text("OK"))
            )
        case .verification:
            return Alert(
                title: Text("Action Message"),
                message: Text("Verification email has been sent. Please check your email inbox to activate it."),
                dismissButton: .default(Text("OK"))
            )
        default:
            return Alert(
                title: Text("Error"),
                message: Text(alertManager.errorMessage),
                dismissButton: .default(Text("OK"))
            )
    }
}

But runtime error happens, the alertManager.alertType is nil
Anything wrong for the code?

alertType = BaseAlert.error as? T, this line will always align nil to alertType. I am not sure how to fix it because I don't really understand your use of generics here.

@JoakimDanielson Is not it a BaseAlert()?

That seems like a whole lot of code for what LocalizedError can do with an enum

Exactly what I was going to write, why not use an enum instead?

In your code T is a subclass of BaseClass and you can't cast from a superclass to a subclass.

@JoakimDanielson, thanks for your support. Basically, I just want to have an extension class since I don't want to add the .error case for all enum types. However, I think I will consider .error as the default case.
